# Images exporting but not opening - java

Tags: java, eclipse, image, io

I am working on a program for a hacking to for FNAF 1 & 2, and for some reason, when I run the program in eclipse, it works just fine, but when I export it, it refuses to run because it says the file is missing, and when I check the jar file, all of the files are there. So, why is this happening?

If you need a class file, Please let me know, normally, I would post it, but it seems like a classpath error I seem to be making.

Comment: How are you loading the resources?

Comment: @MadProgrammer my code to open it is: MainFrame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(GameMenuToUse)))));

Comment: Use something more like `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource/image")`

Comment: I have tried that, it didnt work. The img folder is in the src folder too. Like I said, that code works in eclipse but not outside of it, (jar file) and I checked, and the files were there.

Comment: What path are you using? If you're including the `src` folder then the path is wrong.  `Class#getResources` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` IS the best way to load resources which are embedded within the Jar

Comment: The path to get to the file is: src/image/<imagetouse>.png

Comment: And, when I tried your method I got this result: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image/<imagetouse>.png")` or `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("image/<imagetouse>.png")`. The reason it's returning `null` is because the path is invalid

Comment: ok, let me try that :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nope, still didnt work, still returns null.

Comment: Then the path to your images are incorrect or they don't exist within your Jar

Comment: Do you know a way to list the files?

Comment: The Jar is zip file, you could use `JarFile` or something simular, but you could also just unzip the jar and check that the images files have been included within the correct path